# XSD for WSDL in ColdFusion

Tags: soap, coldfusion, xsd, wsdl, cfc

How do you generate an XSD from the WSDL generated in ColdFusion? I'm not sure how the XSD is useful for creating a SOAP stub but someone needs it, so I need to find a way to generate one.
I tried using some online tools for this but it says "inline definitions".

Hopefully some one knows how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The generated WSDL document includes an XSD property:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

(The above is from Adobe ColdFusion 8)

To find the appropriate XSD for the WSDL in question (in case it differs between Adobe CF, Railo, OpenBD, or versions thereof), just search for "xsd" inside the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the XSD of the WSDL is really what you're looking for. You stated in the question that the purpose of this is actually to generate stubs. The useful information in this case would be an XSD that describes the parameters and/or the response from your service, which I can't tell you how to generate automatically.

Depending on the client system's platform, I suggest that you check out one of these tools:

- [WSDL 2 Java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)
- [wsdl.exe (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)